# java.lang.ClassCastException: android.graphics.drawable.LayerDrawable cannot be cast to android.graphics.drawable.GradientDrawable

Tags: android, android-layout

In my application I am trying change background color for each listView item. And for that I am using shapes which in layer-list. 
Here is my code

drop_shadow.xml

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">

            <gradient android:startColor="#B7B7B7"
                      android:endColor="#A1A1A1"
                      android:angle="270"/>
            <corners android:radius="10dp" />

        </shape>
    </item>

    <item android:top="1px">

        <shape android:shape="rectangle">

            <solid android:color="@color/color11"/>
            <corners android:radius="10dp" />
        </shape>

    </item>

</layer-list>
```

main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout 
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:id="@+id/mainLayout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@drawable/drop_shadow"/>
```

When I call this method I have ClassCastException

```
 private void setRoundedBackground(View view,int color){
        GradientDrawable gradientDrawable;
        gradientDrawable = (GradientDrawable) view.getBackground().mutate();
        gradientDrawable.setColor(getResources().getColor(color));
        gradientDrawable.invalidateSelf();

    }
```

How could I get GradientDrawable from LayerDrawable?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you can create gradient drawable dynamically.. use below class

```
    import android.graphics.drawable.GradientDrawable;

    public class SomeDrawable extends GradientDrawable {

    public SomeDrawable(int pStartColor, int pCenterColor, int pEndColor, int pStrokeWidth, int pStrokeColor, float cornerRadius) {
        super(Orientation.BOTTOM_TOP,new int[]{pStartColor,pCenterColor,pEndColor});
        setStroke(pStrokeWidth,pStrokeColor);
        setShape(GradientDrawable.RECTANGLE);
        setCornerRadius(cornerRadius);
    }
 }
```

and use this class as below

```
SomeDrawable drawable = new SomeDrawable(Color.parseColor("Start Color Code"),Color.parseColor("Center Color Code"),Color.parseColor("End Color Code"),1,Color.BLACK,00);
yourLayout.setBackgroundDrawable(drawable);
```

Answer (score 1):

They are both a subclass of Drawable, so you can't cast them to each other, only to their parent classes.

Comment: What should change here as a best solution

Comment: It depends on what you would like to do with the GradientDrawable

Comment: I want change solid color programmatically (color11 in this example)

Comment: I'm not sure how can you approach this, but [getDrawable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/LayerDrawable.html#getDrawable(int)) may help

Answer (score 0):

i guess it's better to use separacte colors.xml file for the color of the shape, and use  tag, you can delete the .

after all your shape both is the same which is rectangle.

previously i got the same error because i'm using  and  inside the same xml.