# android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable cannot be cast to android.support.v7.widget.RoundRectDrawableWithShadow

Tags: android, android-appcompat, android-cardview

I tried to use CardView in my Application which worked pretty good within my xml Layout. Since I want to generate them in my code and not via xml I tried to set the radius with CardView.setRadius()-Method as suggested by Android Developers (https://developer.android.com/preview/material/ui-widgets.html#cardview).

This does not work at all! I hope someone can help me, with my problem or got a nice workaround with xml layouts.

This is my code:

```
int height = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 100, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
        float radius = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 4, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());

        for (String color : colors) {
            CardView card = new CardView(getActivity());
            TextView text = new TextView(getActivity());
            card.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#"+color));
            card.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(
                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, height));
            card.setRadius(radius); //Error!!
            text.setText(args.get(colors.indexOf(color)) + " - #" + color);
            card.addView(text);
            group.addView(card);
        }
```

This is my Log:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.brobox.materialcolorpalette/com.brobox.materialcolorpalette.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable cannot be cast to android.support.v7.widget.RoundRectDrawableWithShadow
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2212)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2271)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1205)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5146)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:796)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:612)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable cannot be cast to android.support.v7.widget.RoundRectDrawableWithShadow
            at android.support.v7.widget.CardViewEclairMr1.setRadius(CardViewEclairMr1.java:76)
            at android.support.v7.widget.CardView.setRadius(CardView.java:89)
            at com.brobox.materialcolorpalette.ColorFragment.onCreateView(ColorFragment.java:61)
            at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1504)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:942)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1121)
            at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1484)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:571)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1171)
            at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:5241)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2178)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2271)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1205)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5146)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:796)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:612)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

**UPDATE:**
I use the new Lollipop SDK now with Appcompat version 21. Now It does not work at all even, when I try it without setRadius().

New Log:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable cannot be cast to android.support.v7.widget.RoundRectDrawableWithShadow
            at android.support.v7.widget.CardViewEclairMr1.getShadowBackground(CardViewEclairMr1.java:148)
            at android.support.v7.widget.CardViewEclairMr1.getMinWidth(CardViewEclairMr1.java:139)
            at android.support.v7.widget.CardView.onMeasure(CardView.java:181)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16521)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1404)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:695)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16521)
            at android.widget.ScrollView.measureChildWithMargins(ScrollView.java:1226)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
            at android.widget.ScrollView.onMeasure(ScrollView.java:326)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16521)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16521)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16521)
            at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onMeasure(DrawerLayout.java:848)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16521)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16521)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
            at android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onMeasure(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:453)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16521)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16521)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1404)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:695)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16521)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2552)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16521)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:1915)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1109)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1291)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:996)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5603)
            at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:761)
            at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:574)
            at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:544)
            at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:747)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5146)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:796)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:612)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

**Update 2:**
I guess this is a bug by google. So I pointed it out for them: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=77843

Comment: Check [this][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18055679/3322203


i hope this will help you.

Comment: Did you fix this? I just upgraded it's crashing

Comment: I have still this issue. I assume it's a google related bug and therefore I opened one: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=77843

Comment: Thanks, I just starred it and added a comment. I wasted 2 hours on this :(

Answer (score 104, accepted):

I get this error when calling setBackgroundColor() method, which is defined in View class.

```
cardView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffcc"));
```

Instead set**Card**BackgroundColor() method should be called, which is specific to CardViews and defined within CardView class.

This code setting both background colour and the corner radius works for me:

```
cardView.setCardBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffcc"));
cardView.setRadius(50);
```

Comment: I've figured this out myself but forgot about my own question. So I mark your answer as the right answer cause it fixes the problem ;) Thanks for the heads up!

Comment: this one solved my problem too.
i was using materiallist which depends on android.support.v7.widget.CardView. app crashes at
cardView.setBackgroundColor(card.getBackgroundColor());

i used setCardBackgroundColor which solved the crashing issue

Comment: PROBLEM. The above solution solved the exception but when I use cardView.setCardBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT) it drew a gray rectangle around the item, whereas setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT) did not. I do not want that recataangle. I want it to stay TRANSPARENT. 

If one wanders why I draw a transparent background, it is to clear a previous selected item.

Answer (score 6):

I know this is a old question but, if you wanna change a bgcolor of CardView now in android.support.v7.widget.CardView you can just use **setCardBackgroundColor**:

```
 cardView.setCardBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#dddddd"));
```

or just

```
 cv.setCardBackgroundColor(Color.LTGRAY);
```

Answer (score 5):

I found that you cannot set the background of a card view. Even in XML. So this is my workaround:

Put everything in a child layout of the card:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:elevation="10dp">
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/holder_relative_layout"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:gravity="center_vertical">
...
```

Then in code:

```
cardView.row.findViewById(R.id.holder_relative_layout).setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.MediumSeaGreen));
```

Answer (score 1):

The comment about using `SetCardBAckgroundColor` with `CardViews` is correct but I had to cast the Views to `View` as well to get it to compile

```
((CardView)holder.itemView).setCardBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFCC"));
```

All works now.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same crash.
The problem is you are setting background color to CardView programatically in your code.

```
card.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#"+color));
```

comment the line. and set the background and other property in xml itself. Don't do it programatically.

This worked for me. :)

Better you define the different xml file for different situation / data, that you want to differentiate.

Answer (score 0):

This is an easy problem of support library, if you set background drawable first and then color.
They (Google) call getDrawable() to set the background color, if you call color Change. They cast Drawable to RoundRectdrawable and you possibly have another kind of Drawable. For example a ninepatch Drawable. 
Simply override setBackgroundColor() to setBackgroundDrawable(new RoundedDrawable(...))
Not sure about constructor and class name, just look at source code of cardview.

This is the problem:

```
@Override
public void setBackgroundColor(CardViewDelegate cardView, int color) {
   ((RoundRectDrawable) (cardView.getBackground())).setColor(color);
}
```

change to:

```
@Override
public void setBackgroundColor(int color) {
    setBackgroundDrawable(new RoundRectDrawable(color, getRadius()));
}
```