# ColorDrawable cannot be cast to android.support.v7.widget.RoundRectDrawableWithShadow

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-cardview

The issue I am having is basically what is found in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28205143/1489990) but I will still explain below. I am testing on a device with android 5.0.1 and another with 4.2.2. On my device with 5.0.1 I get no errors and everything behaves as expected. On my 4.2.2 device I get the following error:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable cannot be cast to android.support.v7.widget.RoundRectDrawableWithShadow
        at android.support.v7.widget.CardViewEclairMr1.getShadowBackground(CardViewEclairMr1.java:159)
        at android.support.v7.widget.CardViewEclairMr1.getMinWidth(CardViewEclairMr1.java:150)
        at android.support.v7.widget.CardView.onMeasure(CardView.java:181)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15696)
        at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:681)
        at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:461)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15696)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4851)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15696)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4851)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1404)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:695)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15696)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4851)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2261)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15696)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2225)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1290)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1527)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1190)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4860)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:766)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:575)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:542)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:751)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5751)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1083)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:850)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

with the error occurring at this line: `card1.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.White));`

Now as suggested by the linked answer I have tried using `setCardBackgroundColor` however this causes the error to be produced on both my devices. Any suggestions?

The CardView I am attempting to use is a `android.support.v7.widget.CardView`

This is the layout producing the error:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/MainLayout"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="#bbbbb5"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:weightSum="100">


<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="400dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|top"
    android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="-65dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/prem_BACK"
    android:layout_weight="0"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:paddingBottom="0dp"
    android:src="@drawable/plane1" />


<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_marginBottom="40dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_navigate_next_white_48dp" />

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/card_view1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="280dp"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:onClick="card1ClickMethod"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/choice_text1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:onClick="card1ClickMethod"
        android:text="Loret ipsum sample"
        android:textColor="#212121" />
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/card_view2"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="340dp"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:onClick="card2ClickMethod"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/choice_text2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:onClick="card2ClickMethod"
        android:textColor="#212121" />
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/card_view3"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="400dp"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:onClick="card3ClickMethod"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/choice_text3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:onClick="card3ClickMethod"
        android:textColor="#212121" />
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/card_view4"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="460dp"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:onClick="card4ClickMethod"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/choice_text4"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:onClick="card4ClickMethod"
        android:textColor="#212121" />
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/resulttext3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/progressBar1"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|left"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:textSize="15dp" />

<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progressBar1"
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_gravity="right|center_vertical"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/prem_BACK"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
    android:src="@drawable/background4"
    android:visibility="gone" />
```

After reading through the [issue described here](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=77843) I noticed that it has since been closed. As far as I am aware I am using the most updated version of the platform tools and sdk tools and I still have this issue.

After some further testing, I have discovered that the emulator I am using does not have GooglePlayServices. I do not currently have access to a physical device with less than Android 6.0 to test on. Is it a possibility that not having GooglePlayServices could cause this issue?

Comment: Can you post the error that you get when you use setCardBackgroundColor

Comment: Same error as already posted

Comment: can you post the xml that has cardview?

Comment: please check this [link](https://github.com/h6ah4i/android-advancedrecyclerview/issues/21)

Comment: What version of CardView are you using?

Comment: I am using `v7:21.0.+`

Answer (score 2):

This is working for me for cardview inside recycleview

```
 ((CardView)viewholder.itemView).setCardBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
```

Answer (score 2):

You could also **keep both versions of android happy by giving them what they want** rather than trying to force and cast something:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP_MR1) {
       // below lillipop
       view.setCardBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
       // working for lower questions as per another answer posted here
   } else {
        // lollipop and above
        card1.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.White));
        // known to be working for lillipop as per your question
}
```

Basically **call different and working methods for each of the android versions**.

To correctly identify android versions above and below lollipop use `LILLIPOP_MR1` ([Soruce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27623943/android-version-check))

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
card1.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(255, 255, 255));
```

instead of:

```
card1.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.White));
```

Comment: This produces the same error as before on my 4.2.2 device but not on my 5.0.1 device. Sorry for the typo.

Comment: Sorry for the typo. Meant the other way around. Works on 5.0.1 not on 4.2.2

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do what you want is using color filter, I guess. I tried this on 4.2.2 and it works fine.

```
cardView.getBackground().setColorFilter(Color.BLUE, PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
```

Answer (score 1):

By using `setBackgroundColor(int color)` you are actually calling a method on `View`, switching the background. The `CardView` expects a `RoundRectDrawableWithShadow`, which you did just overwrite. Hence the exception.

```
CardView view = (CardView) findViewById(R.id.card);
view.setCardBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
```

Be sure to call `cardView.setCardBackgroundColor(int)` and it works. It works on 4.2.2, and by looking through the cardView source code I'm confident about other apis as well. If this also leads to a crash, it must be a different reason.

Comment: Have you tested this on a physical device or on an emulator? I have only been testing on an emulator and *not* a physical device as I do not have access to one. On my emulator this does not solve the issue.

Comment: @ez4nick tested on a Samsung Galaxy S2 with Api 19...and I find it rather peculiar that this would not work in an emulator, especially since there is no `ColorDrawable` that could cause the crash using that method. Are you sure you don't set the color on multiple posititions?

Answer (score 1):

Probably this resolved by using PublicRoundRectDrawableWithShadow.
Create PublicRoundRectDrawableWithShadow.

```
package android.support.v7.widget;

import android.content.res.Resources;

public class PublicRoundRectDrawableWithShadow extends RoundRectDrawableWithShadow {
    public PublicRoundRectDrawableWithShadow(Resources resources, CardView cardView, int backgroundColor) {
        super(resources, backgroundColor, cardView.getRadius(), cardView.getCardElevation(), cardView.getMaxCardElevation());
    }
}
```

And `setBackground()` like this.

```
    final CardView cardView = (CardView) findViewById(R.id.card_view);
    if (Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP <= Build.VERSION.SDK_INT) {
        cardView.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
    } else {
        cardView.setBackgroundDrawable(new PublicRoundRectDrawableWithShadow(getResources(), cardView, Color.RED));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try below specific line to set `background color` of `card view object`:

```
cardView.setCardBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
```