# android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable cannot be cast to android.graphics.drawable.GradientDrawable

Tags: java, android, drawable

R.drawable.radio_checked.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle"
    android:padding="10dp">
    <!-- you can use any color you want I used here gray color-->
    <solid android:color="@color/radio_button_selected_color" />
    <stroke
        android:width="@dimen/radio_button_stroke_border"
        android:color="@color/radio_button_selected_color" />
</shape>
```

Java code

```
checked =R.drawable.radio_checked;   
Drawable myDrawable = this.resources.getDrawable(checked).mutate(); 
((GradientDrawable)myDrawable).setColor(this.myTintColor);
```

I am having this exception

> android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable cannot be cast to
>   android.graphics.drawable.GradientDrawable

It is very strange because it works fine on all phones except  Samsung Galaxy Note 4 (Android 5.0.1).
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: can you share `checked`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [java.lang.ClassCastException: android.graphics.drawable.LayerDrawable cannot be cast to android.graphics.drawable.GradientDrawable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18055492/java-lang-classcastexception-android-graphics-drawable-layerdrawable-cannot-be)

Comment: make sure you only have 1 resource `radio_checked` in whole your application?

Comment: @Phan Van Linh  Yes but for color I have two radio_button_selected_color. One is from Library. One is the one that I created. Can it be issue?

Comment: @sasha tried test only using 1 color

Comment: You are relying on unspecified behaviour here. The API just gurantees to give you a `Drawable` back.